# how can I prove that this ratio is above or below 1?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to see if the nominator or denominator is bigger that the other, but without having to go through tedious calculations. Can you help me please? The ratio is

> $$\frac{[(x_1)^2 - (x_2)^2]^2}{ (x_1)^4 - (x_2)^4}$$, with $x_1>x_2$.

Thanks!

EDIT: sorry I forgot, the nominator must be squared in that equation!

Comment: Can be both, depending on the value of $x_1^2+x_2^2$.

Comment: @ergon Please edit the question, if the displayed exercise is not the intented one.

Comment: @ergon, what equation are you referring to?  There is no equation in your post.

Comment: yeah I mean the fraction

Comment: You claim that "the denominator must be squared" and yet you edited it so that the numerator is squared.  Why the inconsistency?

Comment: corrected thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hint : $$\frac{x_1^2-x_2^2}{x_1^4-x_2^4}=\frac{1}{x_1^2+x_2^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation reduces to-

$$\frac{(x_1^2-x_2^2)}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_1^2-x_2^2)}=\frac{1}{x_1^2+x_2^2}$$

So,$\displaystyle\frac{1}{y}$ is less than $1$ iff $y>1$